# Find chars in string but prefer consecutive chars with NFA without atomic grouping

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that will find chars anywhere in a string. I would prefer if they would first find consecutive chars though.

Let me give an example, assume `s = 'this is a test test string'` and I'm searching for **`tst`** I would want to find it like so:

```
// Correct
//   v           vv
s = 'this is a test test string'
```

And not:

```
// Incorrect
//   v  v         v
s = 'this is a test test string'
```

---

Also if `s = 'this is a test test tst string'`

```
// Correct
//                       vvv
s = 'this is a test test tst string'
```

A couple of things to note:

- The searching chars are user supplied (`tst` in this case)
- I'm using javascript so I can't support atomi grouping, which I suspect would make this alot easier

My best try is something like this:

```
var find = 'tst';
var rStarts = [];
var rEnds = [];
for (var i = 0; i < find.length - 1; i++) {
    rStarts.push(= '(' + find[i] + find[i + 1]  )
    rEnds.push( find[i] + '[^]*?' + find[i + 1] + ')' );
}
```

But halfway through I realized I had no idea where I was going with it.
Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Why isn't the first one " **t** his i **s** a **t** est test string"? (added spaces because the site would eat the asterisks)

Comment: Because I want the regex to prefer chars that are next to each other, and after that prefer matching in the beginning.

Comment: Okay, so why not "this is a **t** e **st** test string" or "this is a test tes **t st** ring"?

Comment: @Jerry I didn't think it's possible to create a regex that can do that (your first example), and wouldn't want the second because its later in the string. But I'd take either case

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'm still not sure what you're looking for exactly, but maybe that will do for a first try:

```
.*?(t)(s)(t)|.*?(t)(s).*?(t)|.*?(t).*?(s)(t)|(t).*?(s).*?(t)
```

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/aO5gT6)

I'm capturing each of the letters here, but if you don't mind grouping them...

```
.*?(tst)|.*?(ts).*?(t)|.*?(t).*?(st)|(t).*?(s).*?(t)
```

This will match the parts you mentioned in your question.

Comment: This doesn't properly match:

    this is a test test **tst** string

Comment: @MosheK Fixed. I omitted something earlier.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

Compute regexps for all combinations of substrings of the needle in the order you prefer and match them sequentially. So for your test, you can do the following matches:

```
/(tst)/
/(ts).*(t)/
/(t).*(st)/  // <- this one matches
/(t).*(s).*(t)/
```

Computing the regexps is tricky and making them in the right order depends on whether you prefer a 4-1-1 split over a 2-2-2 split.

Comment: Wouldn't this get prohibitively expensive when the input string is over five chars?

Comment: While the number of regexps to match does indeed grow very fast with the number of letters in the needle, i do not think you will have problems with a small-ish number of letters. Keep in mind that you only need to match one at a time, the first match you find should also be the best one, the one you're looking for.

Comment: ... I also thought about a different algorithm using just indexOf and that was indeed my first attempt, but the recursive nature of it bothered me. I'm not even sure if it would be faster.

Answer (score 1):

This finds the shortest collection of a supplied group of letters:

```
function findChars(chars,string)
{
    var rx = new RegExp(chars.split("").join(".*?"),"g");
    var finds = [];
    while(res = rx.exec(string))
    {
        finds.push(res[0]);
        rx.lastIndex -= res[0].length-1;
    }
    finds.sort(function(a,b) { return a.length-b.length; })
    return finds[0];
}
var s2 = 'this is a test test tst string';
console.log(findChars('tst',s2));//"tst"
console.log(findChars('ess',s2));//"est ts"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use lookaheads to mimic atomic groups, as discussed in [this article](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-atomic-groups).  This regex seems to do what want:

```
/^(?:(?=(.*?tst))\1|(?=(.*?ts.+?t))\2|(?=(.*?t.+?st))\3|(?=(.*?t.+?s.+?t))\4)/
```

...or in human-readable form:

```
^
(?:
   (?=(.*?tst))\1
   |
   (?=(.*?ts.+?t))\2
   |
   (?=(.*?t.+?st))\3
   |
   (?=(.*?t.+?s.+?t))\4
)
```

[ref](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-atomic-groups)